# Database for java map service

Tags: java, json, database

I'm running server on Java for a map service. I need to store nearly 12 000 "places of interest" (POI). So, once I receive a request, I need to analyze all the POI and to display only the suitable ones.
Now I've got a JSON file with all these POI. One POI element itself is an object with 7-12 field.
My question is, what database is the most suitable for my task.

Comment: What are your criteria for assessing suitability?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think mongodb will do the job for you. Refer the [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) docs.

Comment: Why do you think so? Because it supports `json` and is hipster? Anything else?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse what? whether it's hipster or not, it's not relevant here. yes it supports JSON, schemaless, decent data manipulation operation speed and many more good things and based on my knowledge and experience I have with mongodb and I thought would suit for this requirement, ok. of course this may not be the best and most accurate answer and I don't know why this user accepted it

Answer (score 0):

I personaly would recommend integrate your POI with ElasticSearch (http://www.elasticsearch.org/). Great tool for search, including full text search, coordinate search (closest distance etc.). Easy to integrate with Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use so called NoSQL DB. Since you are using JSON then there is a great production/enterprise quality open source product called [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/) that stores JSON objects nativelly in its distributed fault tolerant persistent cache store that is [compatible with memcached protocol](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-architecture-apis-memcached-protocol.html). Also [Couchbase has a great integration with ElasticSearch](http://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-and-full-text-search-couchbase-transport-elastic-search) for full-text search capabilities.

I highly recommend [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/) and [ElastiSearch](http://elasticsearch.com) for your task.

Comment: Does Couchbase pay you for these endorsements?

Comment: I'm not at all convinced that Couchbase is appropriate here. It doesn't sound as if he wants a key-value store, and just because he wants `json` doesn't make this the most appropriate choice.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I wish! :) I have selected Couchbase after doing my research on open source distributed cache solutions. Its really great product from memcached authors. Its way better than EhCache/Terracotta.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse With Couchbase's views you could have pretty powerfull query capabilities...then add to that ElasticSearch integration and you should be all set...highly recommend it!